# Have three hours passed?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to set an url to expire 3 hours after the user click forgot password button, but I don't have the idea to compare the current time with the timestamp to check whether it's over 3 hours or not.

Ex. in DB

request_time(timestamp) = 2012-10-22 02:00:00

expire_time(timestamp) = 2012-10-22 05:00:00

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

Comment: Be aware to also include 2012-10-28 - this is the day where daylight saving is switched off for 2012 in Europe.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

if( strtotime('2012-10-22 02:00:00') + 60*60*3 < time() )
{
    // expired
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I'd do:

1. create an integer column in MySQL where I'd store current timestamp when generating the URL (using strtotime('now'))
2. in PHP, when somebody uses the link, I'd check `strtotime('now')` against the stored timestamp

Comment: This is pretty much the only way, otherwise it would be really hard to tell, when you sent out the link.